# Firebreath installation in Windows 7

Tags: c++, activex, npapi, firebreath

**While configuring to work on firebreath plugin in Windows 7, I got errors at this particular command. This configuration is setup on seeing the video on YT.**

All other commands where working. I struck on this particular step.

```
C:\firebreath\TutorialTestPlugin\firebreath>prep2010 . build
Using projects in: "C:\firebreath\TutorialTestPlugin\firebreath"
Generating build files in: "C:\firebreath\TutorialTestPlugin\firebreath\build"
NOTE: The build files in "C:\firebreath\TutorialTestPlugin\firebreath\build" sho
uld *NEVER* be modified directly.
When needed, make project changes in cmake files and re-run this script.
  Project-specific cmake files are found in [plugin dir]\CMakeLists.txt and
  [plugin dir]\Win\projectDef.cmake.
Note that parameters for cmake should be enclosed in double quotes, e.g. "-DVERB
OSE=1"
CMAKE parameters:

C:\firebreath\TutorialTestPlugin\firebreath\build>cmake -G "Visual Studio 10" -D
FB_PROJECTS_DIR="C:\firebreath\TutorialTestPlugin\firebreath"  "C:\firebreath\Tu
torialTestPlugin\firebreath"
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 16.0.30319.1
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10
-- Check for working C compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10
-- Check for working CXX compiler using: Visual Studio 10 -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Visual Studio dir: C:/Program Files/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0
-- Found ATL include dir: C:/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/inc/atl71
-- Found ATL lib dir: C:/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/lib/ATL/i386
-- Found MFC include dir: C:/WinDDK/7600.16385.1/inc/mfc42
-- Balanced size/speed optimization
project dir: C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/addnewlines/ does not seem to be a F
ireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/BSD.html/ does not seem to be a Fire
Breath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/build/ does not seem to be a FireBre
ath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/cmake/ does not seem to be a FireBre
ath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/CMakeLists.txt/ does not seem to be
a FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/common.cmd/ does not seem to be a Fi
reBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/common.sh/ does not seem to be a Fir
eBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/Doxyfile/ does not seem to be a Fire
Breath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/doxygen/ does not seem to be a FireB
reath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/examples/ does not seem to be a Fire
Breath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/fbgen/ does not seem to be a FireBre
ath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/fbgen.py/ does not seem to be a Fire
Breath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/fixtabs/ does not seem to be a FireB
reath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/gen_templates/ does not seem to be a
 FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/Installer/ does not seem to be a Fir
eBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/LGPL.html/ does not seem to be a Fir
eBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2005.cmd/ does not seem to be a
FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2008.cmd/ does not seem to be a
FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2008x64.cmd/ does not seem to be
 a FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2010.cmd/ does not seem to be a
FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2010x64.cmd/ does not seem to be
 a FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2012.cmd/ does not seem to be a
FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2012x64.cmd/ does not seem to be
 a FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2013.cmd/ does not seem to be a
FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prep2013x64.cmd/ does not seem to be
 a FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prepcodeblocks.sh/ does not seem to
be a FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prepeclipse.sh/ does not seem to be
a FireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prepmac.sh/ does not seem to be a Fi
reBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/prepmake.sh/ does not seem to be a F
ireBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/projects/ does not seem to be a Fire
Breath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/README.md/ does not seem to be a Fir
eBreath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/runctags/ does not seem to be a Fire
Breath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/src/ does not seem to be a FireBreat
h Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/tests/ does not seem to be a FireBre
ath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/version/ does not seem to be a FireB
reath Plugin
C:/firebreath/TutorialTestPlugin/firebreath/winprep.cmd/ does not seem to be a F
ireBreath Plugin
No projects found in /.
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:170 (MESSAGE):
  To build examples, run 'prep<ver> examples'


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because the first parameter to prep2010 should be the path where your plugin project(s) reside.  If you haven't moved them from the projects/ directory (which you should) then you could do either:

```
C:\firebreath\TutorialTestPlugin\firebreath>prep2010 projects build
```

or if your plugin project is named "MyTestPlugin" then you could do:

```
C:\firebreath\TutorialTestPlugin\firebreath>prep2010 projects\MyTestPlugin build
```

Basically the first is ideal if you have multiple projects and want to build them together, since it'll use the same builds of the static projects for each, which can speed up compilation time. That's rare, so most often I use the second syntax.

Of course, to me that directory structure you have makes no sense.  I [wrote a blog post](http://colonelpanic.net/2010/11/firebreath-tips-working-with-source-control/) some time ago about what I feel is the best structure for a plugin project, but here is an example of where I might put things in your case:

- C:\plugin_projects\firebreath - FireBreath codebase
- C:\plugin_projects\TutorialTestPlugin - moved from \projects after running fbgen
- C:\plugin_projects\ttp_build - build directory for the above project

You would then run the prep script like so:

```
C:\plugin_projects>firebreath\prep2010 TutorialTestPlugin ttp_build
```

and your disposable build files would be in ttp_build, your project files in TutorialTestPlugin, and all of your firebreath files are untouched in the firebreath dir.

This is just an example; you can do it however you want.  I often add firebreath as a git submodule so I actually run `firebreath\prep2010 . build`, but you need to find what you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this

firebreath\prep2012.cmd .. build